# WooCommerce 404

Tags: woocommerce, http-status-code-404

Every time that I change something on the homepage for WooCommerce and click "Update" or "Preview" it takes me to a 404 page and does not update the site. I have tried this with the original WooCommerce theme as well as my own.

What I have tried:

Permalinks > Save
Disabling all plugins and reenable one by one

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

cPanel/Security/ModSecurity - Disable

Good luck to everyone that might be having this problem in the future.